# Segmentation fault when trying to use a Picoprobe with OpenOCD

Tags: windows, msys2, openocd, raspberry-pi-pico

i wanted to use the new Raspberry Pi Pico as a Picoprobe debugger. I followed this

[tutorial](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf).
I am using Windows. When i try to run it with

```
src/openocd.exe -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg -s tcl
```

i get a segmentation fault. When using -d i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIoWl.png)
I already tried two different Picos.
Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found the Solution on the Github of the Picoprobe.
The Problem is mingw64_x86_64-libusb. When using version 1.0.24 (the most recent version at the moment) it segfaults. You have to use version 1.0.23.

[Here is the link to the issue.](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picoprobe/issues/3)

There is also a link to a

[precompiled version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SgZJepJWYQqCeC7m8se-yJLK9sv_AH8n/view)

of openOCD that should work.